# PHP + form select options

Tags: php, forms, select

I have a select that looks like this, it is written in in HTML and is not rendered via any php,

```
    <select name="position">                                           
<option value="left">Left</option>
    <option value="right">Right</option>
    <option value="centre">Centre</option>
    </select>
```

The value gets sent to database and later on gets returned from the database as a variable in the form of `$v['position']`, using this and my original form how can I make the option that matches the varibale the default selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<select name="position">                                           
    <option value="left" <?php echo $v['position']=='left'?'selected="selected"':'' ?> >Left</option>
    <option value="right" <?php echo $v['position']=='right'?'selected="selected"':'' ?>>Right</option>
    <option value="centre" <?php echo $v['position']=='centre'?'selected="selected"'?:'' >>Centre</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify when the form displayed again.
If immediately when user is submitted the form, you need to insert this snippet to every option:

```
<option value="left"<?php echo $v['position'] == 'left' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Left</option>
<option value="right"<?php echo $v['position'] == 'right' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Right</option>
<option value="centre"<?php echo $v['position'] == 'centre' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Centre</option>
```

OR:

You must iterate through variables via PHP :(

```
$html = '<select name="position">';

$opts = array('left', 'right', 'centre');
foreach($opts as $option)
{
    $html .= '<option value="' . $option . '"';
    $html .= $option == $v['position'] . ' selected' : '';
    $html .= '>' . ucfirst($option) . '</option>';
}
$html .= '</select>';

print $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the options in a loop and check whether the current element equals the value in `$v['position']` and set the `selected` attribute accordingly.

```
<?php
$options = array('left'=>'Left', 'right'=>'Right', 'centre'=>'Centre');
?>

<select name="position">      
<?php foreach($options as $value=>$text):?>                                     
    <option value="<?php echo $value ?>" 
            <?php echo ($v['position'] == $value) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> >
            <?php echo $text ?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) without having to touch your HTML. If this is your HTML:

```
$template = <<< TPL
<select name="position">
    <option value="left">Left</option>
    <option value="right">Right</option>
    <option value="centre">Centre</option>
</select>
TPL;
```

And this is the value that was selected:

```
$value = 'right';
```

You can do

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($template);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node = $xPath->query(sprintf('//option[@value = "%s"]', $value));
if($node->item(0)) {
    $node->item(0)->setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
}
echo $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

And that will output:

```
<select name="position">
    <option value="left">Left</option>
    <option value="right" selected="selected">Right</option>
    <option value="centre">Centre</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="position">                                            
    <option value="left"<?php echo ($v['position'] == 'left') ? ' selected="selected" : ''; ?>>Left</option> 
    <option value="right"<?php echo ($v['position'] == 'right') ? ' selected="selected" : ''; ?>>Right</option> 
    <option value="centre"<?php echo ($v['position'] == 'centre') ? ' selected="selected" : ''; ?>>Centre</option> 
</select>
```